# MySql - Trigger not work - Abort insert

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I had write this trigger but it not work, i recive this error:

> 11:24:11  CREATE TRIGGER check_venduti  AFTER INSERT ON venduti   FOR
>   EACH ROW    BEGIN     SELECT count(*) AS num_rows FROM prodotto WHERE
>   cod_prodotto=NEW.cod_prodotto     if numrows < 0 then      SIGNAL
>   "error"     end   Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near 'if numrows < 0 then      SIGNAL
>   "error"     end' at line 6    0.000 sec

These are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE clienti (cod_cliente integer(4) auto_increment,nome varchar(100),cognome varchar(100),primary key(cod_cliente))Engine=InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE prodotto(cod_prodotto integer(4) auto_increment,descrizione varchar(100),qnt integer(4),primary key(cod_prodotto))Engine=InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE venduti (cod_vendita integer(4)  auto_increment,cod_cliente integer(4) REFERENCES clienti(cod_cliente),cod_prodotto integer(4)
```

REFERENCES prodotto(cod_prodotto),primary key(cod_vendita))Engine=InnoDB;

and this is my trigger:

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER check_venduti
 BEFORE INSERT ON venduti
  FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
    SELECT count(*) AS num_rows FROM prodotto WHERE cod_prodotto=NEW.cod_prodotto
    if num_rows == 0 then
     SIGNAL "error"
    end;
   END;
|
```

now, following your answers i edited my code in this mode:

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER check_venduti
 BEFORE INSERT ON venduti
  FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
    DECLARE num_rows INT;
    SELECT count(*) INTO num_rows FROM prodotto WHERE cod_prodotto=NEW.cod_prodotto;
     if num_rows==0 then
      SIGNAL "error"
     end;
   END;
|
```

but I receive the same error:

Comment: 1. What do you want? 2. How doesn't it work? Does it show error? Does it show wrong result?

Comment: num_rows and then numrows

Comment: I corrected it but still does not work.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax error arises because you have not terminated the `SELECT` statement.

Even if you do terminate the `SELECT` statement, no `num_rows` variable will be defined in the `IF` statement.

You *can* store the result of the `SELECT` statement in a variable for subsequent testing:

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE num_rows INT;
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO num_rows ... ;
  IF num_rows = 0 THEN
    ...
```

However, it appears that what you're *really* trying to do is enforce a [foreign key constraint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) on `venduti.cod_prodotto`:

```
ALTER TABLE venduti
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (cod_prodotto) REFERENCES prodotto (cod_prodotto);
```

Comment: I have inserted ";" at the end of the select statement but it still does not work. I edited my post and i inserted new code following your advice.

Comment: @user2225743: Your edit shows different code to that shown in my answer; in particular, you are attempting to use `==` to test for equality whereas I only use `=`.  SQL does not have a `==` operator.  Also, note that the [`SIGNAL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/signal.html) must be followed by ***`condition_value`***, which must either be the keyword `SQLSTATE` followed by a ***`sqlstate_value`***, or else a previously declared ***`condition_name`***; the string literal `"error"` is neither of those.